# How to join first two child records to parent?

Tags: sql-server, join

I am trying to select the top 25 parent records and join to it the first two child records ordered by date. The parent record can have 0 to n children.

The end result would be something like:

```
P1,  C1, C2
P2,  C1, C2
...
P25, C1, C2
```

I have found an example using max date, but I am having trouble getting a specific row number

```
select top 25 *    
from parentTable p
left join childTable c
on p.Key = c.Key
and c.dateColumn = (
    select Max(c.dateColumn)
    from c
    where p.Key = c.Key
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get what you are looking for using [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
WITH c AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [key] ORDER BY [date] asc) as rn
    ,[key]
    ,[date]
from child
)

SELECT top 25 p.[key], c1.[key], c1.[date], c2.[key], c2.[date]
FROM parent p
LEFT JOIN c c1  
    ON p.[key] = c1.[key]
    AND c1.rn = 1
LEFT JOIN c c2
    ON p.[key] = c2.[key]
    AND c2.rn = 2
```

Check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f252/2) for test data/results

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE.

```
;with cte as (
    select top (25) *    
    from parentTable 
)
select *
from cte p
left join childTable c
    on p.[Key] = c.[Key];
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution (because data set seems to be small) one solution is to use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select  top (25) ... columns ...    
from    parentTable p
outer apply (
    select  top (2) ... columns ...    
    from    childTable c 
    where   p.[Key] = c.[Key]
    order by c.dateColumn desc -- asc ?
) a
-- Most of the times, when top filter is used order by clause should be also used
order by p.dateColumn desc -- asc ? 
-- order by p.idColumn desc -- asc ?
```

Second solution (could be less eficient):

```
select  top (25) ... columns ...    
from    parentTable p
left join (
    select  top (2) ... columns ..., ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by c.[Key] order by c.dateColumn desc) as rn -- asc ?
    from    childTable c 
) a on p.[Key] = a.[Key] and a.rn < 3
-- Most of the times, when top filter is used order by clause should be also used
order by p.dateColumn desc -- asc ? 
-- order by p.idColumn desc -- asc ?
```

Note: at least for the first solution one of following indices could help from the point of view of performance:

```
create index ix_name on dbo.childTable  ([Key], [dateColumn])
--or
create index ix_name on dbo.childTable  ([Key], [dateColumn])
include (... columns from select top(2) clause ...)
```